# C# how to update a list using data from a file

Tags: c#, arrays, list, file-io

I am working on an assignment that requires reading input from two text files. Modifying the first file's data based on the second file's data, and printing the results to a third file.

The first file is an Inventory file that contains an ID number, product name, and quantity, formatted as follows:

> 123 | television | 45
>   124 | computer | 52
>   125 | radio | 20

The second file contains the ID number and change in quantity:

> 123 | -8
>   124 | 7

In a previous question, I inquired about how to read the first file's data into a list. I believe I have accomplished that in the main method in the code below. Also in the code below, I have a loop that will read the lines from the second file and store the ID number as `updateID` and the quantity as `numUpdate`. I would like to use those values to modify the list `Inventory`, but I am unsure how to do that. My first thought when I was looking into this problem was the `.IndexOf` method, but I don't think that would work. What would be the process for having the `Inventory` list updated with the second file's data? Of course, I will eventually want to print the update list to thrid file...but I am not really concerned with for now.

```
class Program
{
    public class InventoryNode
    { 
        public int IDNumber;
        public string Name;
        public int Quantity;

        public InventoryNode()
        {
            IDNumber = 0;
            Name = " ";
            Quantity = 0;
        }

        public InventoryNode(int ID, string InvName, int Number)
        {
            IDNumber = ID;
            Name = InvName;
            Quantity = Number;
        }

        public override string ToString()   // This one is a freebie
        {
            return IDNumber + " | " + Name + " | " + Quantity;
        }
    }

    static void Main(String[] args)
    {
        int ID;
        string InvName;
        int Number;

        string updateID;
        int numUpdate;

        string line; 

        List<InventoryNode> Inventory = new List<InventoryNode>();
        InventoryNode Item = null;

        StreamReader f1 = new StreamReader(args[0]);
        StreamReader f2 = new StreamReader(args[1]);
        StreamWriter p = new StreamWriter(args[2]);

        while ((line = f1.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            string[] currentLine = line.Split('|');
            {
                ID = Convert.ToInt16(currentLine[0]);
                InvName = currentLine[1];
                Number = Convert.ToInt16(currentLine[2]);                    
            }
            Item = new InventoryNode(ID, InvName, Number);
            Inventory.Add(Item);               
        }
        while ((line = f2.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            string[] currentLine2 = line.Split('|');
            updateID = currentLine2[0];
            numUpdate = Convert.ToInt16(currentLine2[1]);
        }
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: `int` is `Int32`, not `Int16`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like

```cs
Inventory.First(node => node.IDNumber == updateID).Quantity += numUpdate;
```

where you read your 2nd file

Edit: I wrote this assuming your 2nd file doesn't contain invalid id's, you'll need a nullcheck

Answer (score 0):

I would not store the first file in a list, but in a [`Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=netframework-4.7.2). This allows you to lookup an item by a key.

```
var Inventory = new Dictionary<int, InventoryNode>();

...

Item = new InventoryNode(ID, InvName, Number);
Inventory.Add(ID, Item);
```

Then lookup an item with

```
while ((line = f2.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    string[] currentLine2 = line.Split('|');
    int id = Convert.ToInt32(currentLine2[0]);
    numUpdate = Convert.ToInt32(currentLine2[1]);
    if (Inventory.TryGetValue(id, out var inventoryNode)) {
        inventoryNode.Quantity += numUpdate;
    }
}
```

Note that looking up in a dictionary is much faster than searching in a list. A dictionary lookup has a near constant time (`O(1)`). I.e. it doesn't depend on the number of items stored. While he access time grows linearly with the list size (`O(n)`).

Also, `Convert.ToInt32` creates an `int` while `Convert.ToInt16` creates a `short`.

Answer (score 0):

You are going in the right direction.

While parsing through the contents of second file you can update `Inventory` List as follows:

```
    while ((line = f2.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        string[] currentLine2 = line.Split('|');
        updateID = currentLine2[0];
        numUpdate = Convert.ToInt32(currentLine2[1]);

        var inventoryNode = Inventory.Where(i=>i.ID == updateID).FirstOrDefault();
        if(inventoryNode != null)
        {
            inventoryNode.Number += numUpdate;
        }
    }
```

This will update the data in the List `Inventory` as these are reference types.

Comment: I added this to see how it worked and I get an error message under `i.ID` in the 7th line. Something about `Program.InventoryNode` not have a definition for ID. Is there a way to fix that?